# How do I traverse through every file in a folder?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a folder called exam. This folder has 3 folders called math, physics and english. All of these folders have some sub folders and files in them. I want to traverse through every folder and print the path of every folder and file on another file called files. I've done this:

```
#!/bin/bash

LOC="/home/school/exam/*"

{
  for f in $LOC 
  do
   echo $f
  done
 } > "files"
```

The exit I get is:

/home/school/exam/math

/home/school/exam/physics

/home/school/exam/english

I can't figure out how to make the code visit and do the same thing to the sub folders of exam. Any suggestions?

PS I'm just a beginner in shell scripting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find /home/school/exam -print > files
```

Comment: this is doing the job. But now that I think of it, I'm doing this script as a part of a team and because everyone in the team does have a different path for the exam folder I don't think that it will work. How can I modify this? I tried find */exam -print > files but it says no such file or directory.

Comment: Ok, I changed it into find ~/exam -print > files and it works. But is it surely going to work on other computers that have the exam folder?

Comment: If I understand your question, just `find exam -print > files` with the parent of the exam directory as the working directory. Using `~/exam` will only work for people who have an `exam` directory in their home directory.

Comment: They have an exam directory. I think it will work. I'll test it as soon as I can. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 2):

With the `globstar` option bash will recurse all filenames in subdirectories when using two adjacent stars

use :

```
shopt -s globstar
for i in /home/school/exam/**
```

The reference here is `man bash`:

```
globstar
                      If set, the pattern ** used in a pathname expansion context
                      will match all files and zero or more directories and
                      subdirectories.  If the pattern is followed by a /, only
                      directories and subdirectories match.
```

and `info bash`:

```
          *      Matches any string, including the null string.  When  the
                 globstar  shell  option  is  enabled,  and * is used in a
                 pathname expansion context, two adjacent  *s  used  as  a
                 single  pattern  will  match  all  files and zero or more
                 directories and subdirectories.  If followed by a /,  two
                 adjacent  *s  will match only directories and subdirecto‐
                 ries.
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `find` command, it could get all files, then you can do something on them, using exec or xargs for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `tree` command which is included in most *nix distributions. (Though Ubuntu is a notable exception - but can be installed via apt-get)

```
LOC="/home/school/exam/"
tree -if $LOC > files
```

Answer (score -1):

How about this to list all your files recursively.

```
for i in *; do ls -l $i ; done
```